# Preventing any Activity from vanish while intent from activty to activity

Tags: android

in my project i have a several activities.. but i have a one (parent) activity... from that activity i intend to other activities for getting data from other activities.. my problem is while indent back to my parent activity all details entered before were gone...can any one assist me how preserve those data's... thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot store information in activity. You have to use other data storing mechanism. In your case, you might need to use preference.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

Comment: k thanks... is there any other way to transfer the data from one activity to another activity, rather than usind indent method..

Comment: hi doc_180...i have some many Edittext in my activity. so will this data stroing mechanism helps better?

Comment: It will work if I understand your problem correctly. You can store the information in shared preference and access the data across your application.